# Splunk query: retrieve top 5 previous _raw events for each matching search event

Tags: splunk

I am trying to retrieve the top 5 previous _raw events followed by a matching search in Splunk.

Let's say, following is my search query and the output:

Query:

```
index=my_index "unhandled error"
```

Result:

```
_time1 header: unhandled error
_time2 header: unhandled error
_time3 header: unhandled error
```

Expectation:

```
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time1 header: unhandled error
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time2 header: unhandled error
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time3 header: unhandled error
```

In between those filtered logs, I have lots of unwanted logs plus few interested logs on the top as follows, without any filter:

```
......lots of unwanted logs....
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time1 header: unhandled error
    ......lots of unwanted logs....
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time2 header: unhandled error
    ......lots of unwanted logs....
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time3 header: unhandled error
```

Note: there is no correlation between unhandled error and interested logs. I just wanted to grab the reason for the unhandled error which are the top 5 _raw logs on the top.

The query should give for 3 `unhandled error` 3*5=15 matches or lines.

Thank you. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to this.

```
index=my_index | eval f=if(_raw LIKE "%unhandled error%",1,0) | streamstats window=6 max(f) as g | where g=1
```

This approach grabs all the data from `my_index`. It then identifies (using field `f`) which of the events contain `unhandled error`, and uses `streamstats` to also tag the previous 6 events in the stream with a flag (`g`). Then its just a matter of removing all the events that haven't been tagged.

The benefit of this approach is that it is a single search that is performed, but the down side is that it needs to parse every event.

A second approach is to use `map`.

```
index=my_index "unhandled error" | eval lt=_time | eval et=_time-60 | map maxsearches=100 search="search index=my_index starttimeu=$et$ endtimeu=$lt$ | tail 6 | eval orig_event=$_serial_id$"
```

In this case, the events that contain `unhandled error` are found first. Then for each of the events found, we use `map` to kick off an extra search, which looks for all events in the previous minute to the error, and then only keep the last 6 events.

The benefit of this approach is that not all the data needs to be searched. The down side is that there are multiple searches involved, and we assume all the previous events happen in the minute prior to the error event. You can change this time period by changing `eval et=_time-60` to `eval et=_time-300` for 5 minutes, for example. We also hard code a limit of 100 searches, which again can be altered to fit your environment.

Which approach is best depends on how much data is in the index and how many `unhandled errors` you expect when you run the search. Try them both, it really comes down to your specific environment.

Comment: In the second map query - how do I include 'unhandled error' also in that window? I see I am getting the cause but it is not followed by key (unhandled error) log while mapping. ```
_time  header: interested_logs1
_time  header: interested_logs2  
_time  header: interested_logs3
_time  header: interested_logs4
_time  header: interested_logs5
_time1 header: unhandled error (missing)
 ```

Comment: Instead of _serial_id, Is there any way to grab the event itself?

Comment: I can do only index=my_index "unhandled error" |eval error_event=_raw | eval lt=_time | eval et=_time-60 | map maxsearches=100 search="search index=my_index starttimeu=$et$ endtimeu=$lt$ | tail 6 | eval orig_event=$_serial_id$ error_msg=$error_event$" | table orig_event, error_msg, _raw is there any better way?

Comment: The second map has a time period up to the event itself. Therefore, it should be included when you do `tail`

Comment: you dont actually need the `_serial_id_` bit, I just used it to group the error events and their history